# During Install I can not create users, and other issues with install

Tags: mysql, windows-services, mysql-workbench

Good Morning Stack Exchange!

Trying to get mysql installed on my personal computer and I've run into a few issues.

1. I can not create a user during install, If I try to add a user during install it fails on the create users step. So I figure I will just add the users after install via sql workbench, which brings me to number 2.
2. After installing mysql server, attempting to connect to the server with mysql workbench just asks me for the password endlessly until it locks me out. I know the password I'm using is correct because when I modify the mysql server instance via the installer it asks for the current root password, adn the password works there.
3. After install, if I stop the mysql service from running mysql workbench loads without issue.
4. Mysql installer can not stop the mysql service, to modify an install I have to manually stop the service.

The common thread to all of these issues is the windows service for mysql.

Troubleshooting steps

- verified port 3306 was open in the firewall
- disable firewall entirely
- Turned off anti-virus
- uninstalled anti-virus
- Multiple restarts of both the service and computer
- Uninstalled all my sql components and reinstalled (multiple times)
- changed the root password via command shell (via [This MySQL guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.7/en/resetting-permissions-windows.html) for recovering the root password)
- Downloaded the installer again in case there was a corruption of my original file.

So I'm pretty stumped, I've been at this for two days and I don't feel any closer to a solution.

Configuration info:
windows 10 (intel core i-5, 16 gigs of ram, 96 gigs of open space on SSD)
MYSql Installer version 8.0.13.0

Comment: Can u not reset the root password to get in.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.7/en/resetting-permissions-windows.html

Comment: I was able to change the password via following the link in the troubleshooting steps, which is the same as the one you provided. However the password doesn't appear to be the issue, because I was able to modify the installation via the installer which requires the root password.

Comment: Since it’s asking for password endlessly as u said, there may be an issue with the password. In any case dig for the logs for more clues as what’s really going on.

Comment: Have you tried to login without password? Lot of MySQL installation apps install it without root password.

Comment: @sakura Kinomoto I did, and got the same result.

Comment: Try to use mysql command line, and login with and without password.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would check is the logs. 
However, given the info you provided it sounds like default settings are there but no root@localhost user password or root@127.0.0.1. 
Check the my.ini existence for details and logs. 
You may have to follow this to create the config file if it doesn’t exist - follow the link below.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21835/mysql-workbench-asking-for-password

Error log location in windows:
The error log is located in the data directory specified in your my.ini file. The default data directory location is C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server......